# Exist is always coming TRUE in UFT when using index to identify Browser

Tags: ui-automation, qtp, hp-uft

I've to get the number of opened browsers having some title. The approach that I used was using the index. But the problem is, whatever index I pass, Exist function is always returning true.

```
Browser("openurl:=.*something.*", "index:=0").Exist  => True
```

when i change the index to 10 or some other number, it still returns me True even if there is only one browser window. My problem statement is to find any new browser window opened after a click of a button, this window can be a pdf or csv file. After identifying the window (by using index in my case) I've to get the visible text of the window.

PS: I'm new to UFT, have worked on automation using selenium tool.

Comment: Have you tried it without the `openurl` property included?

Comment: Yes I did, tried with micclass as well but didn't helped

Comment: Did you try using other properties, such as `name` or `title` (sorry I've forgot the exact Browser properties and don't have access to UFT). Also, did you try with `CreationTime`?

Comment: @VictorMoraes yes I tried CreationTime as well. There also I get the same issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `index` (or any ordinal identifier like `CreationTime`) are used only if the description matches multiple `Browser`s, if the description you supply only matches one object it will be ignored.

I tried with two open tabs and got the following results:

```
Print Browser("opentitle:=.*", "index:=10").Exist         ' => False
Print Browser("opentitle:=.*Example*", "index:=10").Exist ' => True
```

If you're seeing different results I would suggest try using the undocumented function `Highlight` to see which `Browser` UFT thinks matches your description.

Comment: I've a single browser having multiple tabs.

Comment: As far as UFT is concerned a tab is a `Browser`

Comment: So you mean to say, if there is only single browser any index will return true. Right?

Comment: If the description describes exactly one `Browser` (could be a tab or a separate browser window) then `index` will be ignored.

Comment: I think I got my problem, when i click the button I expect index 1 to be valid. But there is only one browser present and hence, index is getting ignored.

Comment: How would you suggest to deal with this issue ?

Comment: If you know the description of the browser you can try seeing if it exists. Otherwise you can try doing `Browser("...").GetROProperty("number of tabs")`

Comment: I don't have any other description. I was already using number of tabs to identify if a new window has opened. I can live with it :)